# Covering $X^2$ with countable subsets of $X$ for uncountable set $X$

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Let $X$ be an uncountable set and consider a map $x\mapsto C_x$ assigning to every $x\in X$ a countable subset $C_x$ of $X$. Now for any $x\in X$ define $$R_x:=\{x'\in X|x\in C_{x'}\}.$$
Obviously $R_x$ can be any subset of $X$. It is also clear that $R_x=X$ can hold for at most countably many $x$. But what happens if $R_x$ is just a bit smaller than $X$? Specifically, is it possible that $R_x$ is co-countable for all $x$?

My intuition says NO. It is based on the following picture. For each $x$ $C_x$ can be taken to define a column in $X^2$: $$C_x':=\{(x,y)\in X^2|y\in C_x\}.$$ The union of all these columns defines a very "sparse" subset of $X^2$. The union can also be written as the union of all rows. If these rows would all be co-countable, the set doesn't look that "sparse" anymore. However, making this precise by turning $X^2$ into a measure space doesn't seem the way to go as the sets $C_x$ can be very wild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the set of countable ordinals, and let $C_x=\{w\in X\mid w \le x\}$.

Then for all $x\in X,\;C_x$ is countable, but $R_x$ is co-countable.

Comment: Thank you. I was already afraid the answer would head in this direction. I was thinking of constructions with $X$ the unit interval. By your example those exist if we assume CH, thus popping the question if they also exist without CH. But maybe it's better to not go down that rabbit hole.

Comment: @Ronnie Hermens: As far as I know, the existence of a least uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$ doesn't require the Continuum Hypothesis. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal

Comment: @quasi If CH holds, there is an example with $X=[0,1]$. In the comment, Ronnie is asking whether there is an example with $X=[0,1]$ without having to assume CH.

Comment: @Andrés E. Caicedo: Yes, I didn't read Ronnie Hermens's comment carefully. Agreed that for $X=[0,1]$, if we assume CH, then sets $C_x$ satisfying the requirements exist.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thank you for clarifying my comment above. Although quasi's answer works perfectly, it doesn't help with countering my flawed intuition (as expressed in the question). Quasi's answer uses a particular property of $\omega_1$ that I find difficult to spot in other sets (without using CH). Basically, any other example of an $X$ doing the job may shed some light on the matter.